# Logistic regression: binary dependent variable ~ continuous independent variable. Is it valid to assign "more than" values?

Tags: logistic, binary-data, censoring

I have a dataset of about 3,500 employees with two variables: whether they left or stayed; and how many days they worked at the same location. I want to build a logistic regression model to see whether staying in one place for a long time can explain leaving/staying.

The problem is that I only have about a year's worth of data. This means that for 85% of the employees the number of days is "at least 400" but it could be 4,000, too, as far as we know. In other words in my dataset they have only ever been in one location. Most of these employees are stayers but about 300 are leavers.

In this data environment, is it valid to build a logistic regression model by assigning 400 days to any employee who only ever had one location?

(Or should I turn the number of days into categories, and go for Chi-squared?)

Comment: This is a form of data *censoring* rather than missing data.  It is the same kind of censoring dealt with in survival analysis.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, @whuber, I was not aware of this (very much a beginner on the statistics journey). I hope someone can find the time to answer.

Comment: In the meantime, check out our [posts on survival analysis with binary outcomes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=survival+binary).  You will likely find good answers are already here.

Comment: @whuber censoring and the survival analysis approach to it deals with censoring in the outcome, not the predictor, right? This seems like a case of missing data/measurement error in the predictor. I don't think this is easily solvable without very strong assumptions, but you could do a sensitivity analysis comparing best case (all at 400) to worse case (all at 4000) and see how much the results change.

Comment: @Noah Replacing "left" with "died" and "worked at the same location" with "time in treatment," this becomes a classic textbook question in survival analysis.

Comment: @whuber Interesting, that's a clever way to look at it.